# Scaleup and Scale Down of imported DWG file in the Eyeshot Model

Tags: dwg

I imported the DWG file into the eyeshot model. For reading file I used ReadAutodesk class. I want to apply Scaleup and Scaledown on the imported DWG file. I don’t understand how to do that. Can you please help me.

This is code I used.

```
private void RibbonRadioButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
     OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog() {
         Filter = "DWG File|*.dwg|pdf file|*.pdf",
         Multiselect = false,
         AddExtension = true,
         CheckFileExists = true,
         CheckPathExists = true
    };

    string fileName = null;
    if (fileName != null || openFileDialog1.ShowDialog().Value) {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(delegate { }));
        var rfa = new ReadAutodesk(fileName != null ? fileName : openFileDialog1.FileName);
        ScaleTransform aa = new ScaleTransform(2,2.5,1,1);
        rfa.DoWork();
        rfa.AddToScene(model1);
              
        Entity[] toAdd = model1.Entities.Explode();
        model1.RenderTransform = aa;  
        model1.ZoomFit();
        model1.Entities.AddRange(toAdd, NOT_MODIFIED_COLOR);
        model1.SetView(viewType.Top);

        // Fits the model in the viewport
        model1.Invalidate();
    }
}
```